# How can I import a string values stored in a variable of an external file, in typescript, without losing special characters content?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, character-encoding

I'm importing a variable stored in a separated file `.ts`, and this file contains special characters, specifically accents chars of some languages like French or Spanish.

The problem I have is that once I require it, the content looses the special chars content replacing it by the typical `Ã*`.

By the moment I've solved the issue using unicodes and/or HTML entities in the original text, but I would like to maintain the original text without it and apply some parsing function instead (or another solution).

How can I maintain the content without to need to change the original text encoding it?

This is a simple example of my situation:

· mainScript.ts:

```
  public getDataVar() {
    const data = require('./data.ts');
    console.log('data', data); // here the content is already wrong
    return data;
  }
```

· data.ts:

```
export var data = {
  'example': 'El cielo está nublado. Probablemente lloverá'
}
```

P.S.: Solutions that changes the process are welcomed, but what I would want ideally is to maintain the way I get this data.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using node?  or requirejs?  or something else?

Comment: I'm using Node.

Comment: And do you know the encoding of `data.ts`?  `require()` in node expects it to be `utf8` but I'm guessing it's some other encoding.

Comment: I've found out by the terminal: `data.ts: text/plain; charset=utf-8`. (I created it through atom)

Comment: Oh, maybe it's not the encoding... I think you shouldn't be requiring a *TypeScript* file, but the *JavaScript* file to which it is compiled by tsc.  Someone with more experience than I with using modules in TypeScript might have a suggestion for how to target the js file.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz! I will wait if luckily someone has a suggestion for that.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it adding the [webpack-encoding-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-encoding-plugin) plugin and adding this specs to webpack.config.js file:

```
var EncodingPlugin = require('webpack-encoding-plugin');
module.exports = {
[...]
    plugins: [
          new EncodingPlugin({
          encoding: 'utf16'
        })
    ]
}
```